# How to make DAX USERELATIONSHIP work with Grandparent Relationship

Tags: powerbi, ssas, relationship, dax

OK. So this is going to be fairly hard to explain, but I will give it my best try.

I have four tables that have relationships connecting all of them.

- Table A is connected to Table B with a one way filter from B to A.
- Table B is connected to Table C with a two way filter from B to C and C to B.
- Lastly, I have a DateTable that is connected to table C via a Date relationship.

By default, the DateTable is filtering on standard relationship not the one listed above. As a result, I have to use a USERELATIONSHIP to look at the correct date.

I am using DAX like this, but it is throwing a SQL error when it runs.

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER('Table A',
            'Table A'[Field1] = "Turtle" ||
            'Table A'[Field1] = "Zebra"
        )
    ), USERELATIONSHIP('Date'[Date], 'Table C'[SpecialDateKey])
)
```

I think the problem is that I am not applying the USERELATIONSHIP to the Parent (Table B) but instead the Grandparent (Table C). Is there a standard way to make this relationship work or would I be better off to try and combine Table B and Table C?

Comment: Please provide the model image (relationship diagram) from PowerBI. You are saying you get an error, please provide the error you are getting. I am lost when you say: Table A is connected to Table B want a one way filter? I am not aware tables can be connected by filters, the are only connected by relationships.

Comment: Do you have INACTIVE relationship between 'Date' and 'Table C' on columns that you specified in function?

An error is returned if any of the columns named as an argument is not part of a relationship or the arguments belong to different relationships.